# Ionic Cordova Getting error code 2 when saving pdf file on Android 13

Tags: android, angular, android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an application that saves files downloaded from web to the phone. when upgrading to android 13, it doesnot work. All changes prior that worked on both android 11 and 12. Also permission requests is not shown, although i am aware of the permission changes in Android 13. just not sure if it is checked in the background

#### What is expected to happen?

I expected the file to be saved on the phone, and i can trigger google drive to open the file so the user can view the pdf file.

#### What does actually happen?

I am getting error { "code": 2 } i.e SECURITY_ERR when i try to create the file. Looking it up, it relates to permission issue

### Information

my current code to save the file
` async saveImageToDevice(folderpath,filename,content,contentType){

```
const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create();
await loading.present();

//Determine a native file path to save to
let filePath = '';
if(this.plt.is('android')) {
  filePath = this.file.externalRootDirectory + "/Download";
} else if(this.plt.is('ios')) {
  filePath = this.file.documentsDirectory;
} else {
  this.file.cacheDirectory
}
// let filePath = (this.plt.is('android')) ? this.file.externalRootDirectory : this.file.cacheDirectory;

//Write the file
if (this.plt.is("pwa")) {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
    content
  );
  const link = window.document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute("download", filename);
  window.document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  link.remove();
  await loading.dismiss();
} else {
  return this.file.writeFile(
    filePath,
    filename,
    content,
    { replace: true}
  ).then((success)=> {
    loading.dismiss();
    this.logging.log("File created Succesfully" + JSON.stringify(success))
    this.alertMessage('File downloaded to device. Check downloads for the receipt file.', filename)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    loading.dismiss();
    this.logging.error("Error creating file: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    this.notification.showAlert("Error","Error creating file: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    throw err;  //Rethrow - will be caught by caller
  });
}
```

}`

#### Version information

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.19.1 (C:\Users....\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.2.13
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.2.13
@angular/cli                  : 14.2.13
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
Cordova Platforms : android 12.0.1
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 19 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res                          : 0.15.4
native-run (update available: 1.7.2) : 1.6.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
NodeJS            : v16.14.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm               : 8.5.0
OS                : Windows 10

#### Package.json

`{ ... "dependencies": { ... "@awesome-cordova-plugins/file": "^6.4.0", ... }, "devDependencies": { ... "cordova-plugin-file": "^8.0.0", ... }, "description": "An Ionic project", "cordova": { "plugins": { ... "cordova-plugin-file": { "ANDROIDX_WEBKIT_VERSION": "1.4.0" } }, "platforms": [ "android" ] } }`